# Hibernating my Ubuntu 10.10 takes a bit too long

Tags: 10.10, hibernate

It takes about 5 minutes most of the time to hibernate my Ubuntu 10.10. This is unacceptable! Is there a work-around I could use to improve the situation? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the uswsusp package.  It compresses the data as it writes it out so the process goes faster.  5 minutes seems a bit extreme though, pointing to a more serious hardware problem.

Comment: Works effortlessly, Thanks alot @psusi, It beats me why this is not installed by default. I can hibernate under 15 seconds  and start up again under 10 seconds.

Comment: After scanning this question I decided to try the package myself, and I am impressed with the decrease in the time to hibernate.  Thanks.